# Distributing TextViews with layout_constraintVertical_weight

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I am having a slight problem with `layout_constraintVertical_weight`, I am trying to get the two TextViews to share the amount of available vertical space in the assigned area but without me manually assigning this does not happen. I have tried adding in `0dp` for the height but that doesn’t work, however it works flawlessly for the width.  This is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Layout for a single list item -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:background="@color/tan_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@color/category_colors"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
            tools:text="text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@color/category_numbers"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
            tools:text="text2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is an img of how the layout looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOs9y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done using a guideline. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for a single list item -->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:background="@color/tan_background">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/miwok_text_view"
        tools:text="text2" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Not sure it's the best way, but it works :)

Comment: Nope! The question is about weight but not about guid line work around!

Answer (score 6):

You have to create a chain with layout_height being 0dp for this to work

in order to create a chain ALL views in the chain must contain a constraint to the previous AND the next item in that chain, and the first one and the last one must be aligned to the parent

in your case in order for this to work you have to do something like this:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        --this should be 0dp otherwise it will not use weight
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        ---this is what you have to add--
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/default_text_view"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        tools:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        -- again 0dp otherwise weight is ignored
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        -- again add this to create a chain
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/miwok_text_view"


        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        tools:text="text2" />
```

After the above changes weights should work correctly

Comment: as a side note , something I figured out recently, in order to create a chain you don't have to have the first and last item constrained to the parent, you can have them constrained to another view (haven't tested for multiple, but one seems to work) so if you have the start of the chain be Top_toTopOf="@id/myview" and the last view of the chain Bottom_toBottomOf="@id/myview" this should also work